# [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'paid' of null"

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I am going to the foreach loop of an array. when i try to get the key , it shows an error.

if i display whole raw array it displays all the data.

```
<span v-for="bal in ballance">
     <b >
       {{bal}}
      </b>
 </span>
```

//it displays

```
{ "id": 3, "user_id": 2, "party_id": 7, "doc_no": "tck7nb", "bill_no": "123", "paid": 50, "ballance": 50, "remarks": "erer"}
{ "id": 4, "user_id": 2, "party_id": 7, "doc_no": "tck7nb", "bill_no": "123", "paid": 50, "ballance": 50, "remarks": "erer"}
```

but if if do like below, it gives the me the error mentioned in the title

```
 <span v-for="bal in ballance">
    <b >
      {{bal.paid}}
    </b>
   </span>
```

how to resolveve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check to make sure `bal` is not [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy):

```
<span v-for="bal in ballance">
  <b v-if="bal">
    {{bal.paid}}
  </b>
 </span>
```

My assumption would be there is an empty entry in the array and this is causing the issue so checking `bal` is valid before using it's props is wise.

You could even do it on the `span` instead, like: `<span v-for="bal in ballance" v-if="bal">`

Comment: Yeah, that was the issue